# Chart.js tooltip at any point on the chart

Tags: tooltip, chart.js

How do I get chart.js tooltip to work in the following way:

example : http://watchstocks.herokuapp.com/

I need the tooltip at any point on the graph, not just on a data point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a similar result using the [tootip `position` property](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#position-modes) (the documentation includes an example of implementing a custom positioner if you prefer):

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        position: 'nearest'
    }
}
```

See the Chart.js [samples page for a demo](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/positioning.html).

Examples with more elaborate interactions are [also available](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/tooltips/interactions.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help. What really worked for me is this -
mode: 'index', intersect: false