# Get chart.js to display a tooltip any time the cursor intersects the line?

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

[In this demo I'm trying to get chart.js](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zuqgkx?file=index.ts) to display a tooltip at the place where the cursor intersect the line.

[This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390011/chart-js-tooltip-at-any-point-on-the-chart) and I tried the options pointed out, however no love.

```
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
        position: 'nearest',
      },
    },
```

Any ideas?